# Encoding options not functioning in Word 2013?

Tags: ms-word

I received files from a client that use a mixture of English and an Arabic alphabet, but upon opening, symbols have replaced the Arabic letters.

I've tried using a couple different word processors, and I've found an answer from Microsoft help center that *should* solve my problem.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-HA010121249.aspx#BM2

However, I get stuck after #4. The instructions say that once you check off the option to "Confirm file format conversion on open", the Conversion dialogue will open automatically when you open a document ... but this is just not happening. I've tried restarting the program.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: I think this is off-topic for SO, maybe better for SuperUser, but have   you closed all instances of MS Word before you try and open the document?